# .htaccess: RewriteCond syntax?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, syntax

I'm using Drupal 6. Typically, when the user requests a URL for which Drupal has no response, it uses index.php as the error document. However, I'd like to suspend this behavior for a specific URL. How can I do this?

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=fail
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Where "fail" is the path I want to block. So www.example.com/fail should result in a 404.

Incidentally, what does `[L, QSA]` do? I've looked at [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) without luck.

Answer (score 1):

QSA = Query String Append
L = Last Rule

it's [there](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/fail*